GO Grpc client and C++ Grpc server
We are doing some POC where client is GO GRPC and server is C++ GRPC (Sync based server)

GO GRPC client connected to C++ GRPC server on main thread.
GO client calls one of the RPC method on C++ GRPC server which on main thread.

Wanted to check if C++ GRPC server supports any in built multithreading so that any RPC call on main thread will be handled on worker threads without loading much on main thread so it will handle more requests.
We tried one end-to-end call from client to server which is currently handled on main thread of c++ GRPC server, wanted to check if any built-in support in c++ GRPC server that will distribute load to other threads (worker) without much impacting load on main thread.

gRPC C++ makes an extensive use of multithreading and the requests will be handled by a thread from a thread pool.
To further leverage the support, we recommend to use the callback API, e.g. see this example which would allow asynchronously finishing the request handling.
